# CREATING INDEX SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Recently I was put into database fine tuning. I have some ideas about SQL Server and decided to create some index.

Referred this http://sqlserverplanet.com/ddl/create-index

But i don't understand how other types of Index like `INCLUDE`, `WITH` options will help. I tried google to but failed to see a simple description when to use those.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_NC_PresidentNumber
ON dbo.Presidents (PresidentNumber)
INCLUDE (President,YearsInOffice,RatingPoints)
WHERE ElectoralVotes IS NOT NULL

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_NC_PresidentNumber
ON dbo.Presidents (PresidentNumber)
WITH ( DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW )

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_NC_PresidentNumber
ON dbo.Presidents (PresidentNumber)
WITH ( DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE )
```

What scenario I should use the above? Will they increase performance?

Answer (score 4):

Data compression will help your query performance too, since after compression, when you run a query, less page/extent will be loaded, since I/O is reduced, reducing I/O is always a good choice.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to the with datacompression option, but the Include option can definitely improve performance.  If you select only the PresidentNumber and one or more of President, YearsInOffice, or RatingPoints columns, and the ElectoralVotes is not null, then your query will get values from the index itself and not have to touch the underlying table.  If your table has additional columns and you include one of those in your query then it will have to retrieve values from the table as well as the index.

---

```
Select top 20 PresidentNumber, President, YearsInOffice, RatingPoints
From Presidents
where ElectoralVotes IS NOT NULL
```

The above query will only read from IX_NC_PresidentNumber and not have to pull data from the Presidents table because all columns from the query are included in the index

```
Select top 20 PresidentNumber, President, YearsInOffice, PoliticalParty
From Presidents
where ElectoralVotes IS NOT NULL
```

This query will use the index IX_NC_PresidentNumber and the Presidents table as well because the PoliticalParty column in the query is not included in the index.

```
Select PresidentNumber, President, YearsInOffice, RatingPoints
From Presidents
Where RatingPoints > 50
```

This query will most likely end up doing a table scan because the where clause in the query versus the where clause used in the index don't match, and there no limit on the rowcount.

Comment: Could you please add sample query here. It will easily help me to think and understand :)

Comment: Looks fine. So we need to add Index to all the columns in SELECT statement to get a good performance? to avoid Table scan.

Comment: No, you don't need to add all the columns to the index to avoid table scan.  You need to have indexes on columns you use in the where clause to avoid table scans.  The performance increase you will see from having all the columns in the index is relatively minor as the index includes pointers to the rows.  The big gain is having indexes on the filter columns.